# Regex matching only the first occurrence doesn't work

Tags: regex

Need to match only the first pair of curly brackets (and the following semicolon).

tried regex `/({.*};)/`

String example - `{text 1}; {text 2};`

Expected result `{text 1};`

Current result `{text 1}; {text 2};`

Adding `?` doesnt seem to work here - `/({.*};?)/`

Thanks

Comment: Omit the `g` from `/g` which matches all occurrences

Comment: Ah, ok, was playing on Regex Pal - cant remove from there, I think :) Thanks, will try

Comment: @The fourth bird - for some reason it doesnt work

Comment: I forgot, you also have to make the quantifier non greedy `{.*?};` or like this `{[^{}]*};`

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind to provide an answer? Maybe even with explanation what "greedy" supposed to be meaning? :) Example I provided was simplified, so i still need to adopt it...

Comment: It is asked frequently, and I am sure there are duplicates. But you can read about it for example here https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html and here https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html or here at the **Quantifiers** section https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/5424988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lone `*` is called a [*greedy* operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), because it will try to match as much of the source as possible: in your case, up to the second `}`.

You can use the *lazy* operator `*?`, which will match as short as possible, here up to the first `}`.

Like such:

```
/({.*?};)/
```

Or you can use a [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), noted with square brackets, that excludes the closing bracket: `[^}]` (the `^` negates the content of the set) instead of the dot:

```
/({[^}]*};)/
```

(I personnally prefer this solution because it is more explicit as to which characters are allowed/restricted from the match, but in your case it's a simple matter of taste).

Your suggestion of adding a `?` after the semicolon is not relevant because it will only apply to the semicolon, not the whole group.

Comment: [398](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/22444?lq=1) + [53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2503413?lq=1) same questions have already been answered. Next time, please consider flagging such questions as duplicates.